# Remove buttons from detail component

Tags: visualforce

I have a visualforce page that overrides the standard Quote view. I am using the `<apex:detail />` component to display all the fields in the page layout, which shows the buttons at the top and bottom of the component output. Is there a way to remove/hide the buttons at the bottom?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide it with CSS:

```
<style>
#bottomButtonRow {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox